# Software to merge template PDF to many PDF files using a batch file

Tags: pdf, merge

I need to create a PDF blank template dispatch note with terms and conditions printed on the back of each page.  I need to then merge the template (front of the page) document with many individual PDF dispatch notes and print or email them.  I need to run this job in batch in a job scheduler.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of job that [PDF TK Server](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) is perfect for.

It is a free, command line utility for Windows, Mac or Linux.

PDFtk Server can:

- Merge PDF Documents or Collate PDF Page Scans
- Split PDF Pages into a New Document
- Rotate PDF Documents or Pages
- Decrypt Input as Necessary (Password Required)
- Encrypt Output as Desired
- Fill PDF Forms with X/FDF Data and/or Flatten Forms
- Generate FDF Data Stencils from PDF Forms
- Apply a Background Watermark or a Foreground Stamp
- Report PDF Metrics, Bookmarks and Metadata
- Add/Update PDF Bookmarks or Metadata
- Attach Files to PDF Pages or the PDF Document
- Unpack PDF Attachments
- Burst a PDF Document into Single Pages